# Mi tabla en Highcharts muestra mas categorías (en numeros) de las que hay y están en diagonal

Tags: javascript, angular, responsive, highcharts

Mi problema es que tengo las categorías y cuando achico la proporción de la pantalla se me ponen en diagonal.

Esta es mi tabla en estado normal:

[image: Acá se ve la tabla en estado normal]

Esta es mi tabla cuando achico la pantalla:

[image: Se muestra la tabla con menor width]

Como se puede ver, las categorías aparecen en diagonal.

Una opción que pensé, fue eliminar todas las fechas en meses y quedarme solo con 3 (La inicial, la del medio y la final). Esto también me va a ayudar para el futuro (porque van a aparecer muchísimos mas datos y seria agobiante ver tantas fechas).

Al añadir solamente 3 fechas, lo que ocurre es que como tengo mas datos que categorías, se autocompletan con números (cosa que no quiero).

[image: Los 3 valores que quiero pero con numeros].

Cabe aclarar que intente llenar las categorías con strings vacíos salvo los meses que quería. Si bien en un principio aparece todo bien. Cuando vuelvo a achicar la pantalla siguen apareciendo en diagonal porque detecta que están los 5.

Mi objetivo es que aparezcan esos 3 meses pero ordenados y sin números.

Mis categorías son de tipo STRING no de tipo DATE.

Un ejemplo simple del código en Angular:
Component.html:

```
<highcharts-chart class="grafica" [Highcharts]="Highcharts [options]="chartOptions"></highcharts-chart>
```

Component.ts:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {

  xAxis: {
    categories: ["May 22", "Jun 22", "Ene 23"],

  }, series: [{

      data: [["20 de Mayo", 3],["25 de Mayo", 8],["30 de Junio", 10],["27 de Agosto", 11], ["30 de Diciembre", 20] ],

      type: 'line',
      color: '#0F2A6D',
      zIndex: 3,
      marker: { enabled: false },
    },],;
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Podrías agregar el código correspondiente a tu error, para poder replicarlo, de favor?

Comment: Traigo datos desde una falsa api y otros calculos más, pero pongo unos datos básicos para que quede similar.